# psycopg2 create table if not exists and return exists result

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a problem figuring out how I can create a table using psycopg2, with IF NOT EXISTS statement, and getting the NOT EXISTS result

The issue is that I'm creating a table, and running some CREATE INDEX / UNIQUE CONSTRAINT after it was created. If the table already exists - there is no need to create the indexes or constraints

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2 connection instance have attribute called notices

what I do is:

```
notice_msg = 'NOTICE:  relation \"{}\" already exists, skipping\n'.format(tbl_name)
if notice_msg not in self.conn.notices:
        create_index()
        create_unique_constraint()
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I ended up adding AUTOCOMMIT = true

This is the only way I can make sure all workers see when a table is created